# How to get value from function one with deferred object into function two?

Tags: jquery

I've been able to implement a deferred object, but am now trying to access a value from the first function within the second function.

I'm not sure if I'm just not understanding what I should be returning in `functionOne()`, or if deferred objects aren't designed to work in this way.

How do I access results from `functionOne()`'s `getJSON()` in the second function?

```
function functionOne(x, y) {
    var r = $.Deferred();
    $.getJSON("/my_path", {
        k1: x,
        k2: y,
        format: 'json'
    }, function (results) {

    });

    setTimeout(function () {
        r.resolve();
    }, 2500);

    return r;
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    functionOne(x, y).done(function (results) {
        // how do i access keys from functionOne's getJSON results?
        var myVar1 = results.great_key_1;
        var myVar2 = results.great_key_2;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just return the promise returned by `$.ajax`

```
function functionOne(x, y) {
    return $.getJSON("/my_path", {
        k1: x,
        k2: y,
        format: 'json'
    });
}
```

Your version is a bit of an anti-pattern but to see it work you need to pass in the ajax results to `resolve()`. I am only showing this since you have a delay implemented and will be able to see the full effect of that delay. Otherwise you should really use my first version

```
function functionOne(x, y) {
    var r = $.Deferred();
    $.getJSON("/my_path", {
        k1: x,
        k2: y,
        format: 'json'
    }, function (results) {
         setTimeout(function () {
            r.resolve(results);// resolve with data
         }, 2500);
    });

    return r.promise;
}
```